# How to compare and find desired result from a table

Tags: automation, blueprism, rpa

I am using the Blueprism Surface Automation training application[App1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QaRu.png)[App2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6lIl.png), and i want to find account using last name as search filter. Here i got multiple matches and want to select one result based on the first name [Result_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc1og.png). 
How to do that? Any suggestions.

Meanwhile i was trying this,
Tried using accessibility mode where i select the first name once and then just change the y coordinate of the region and read the value, but i can't find any option to do that. There is one option [Movable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLaoz.png), but not sure how to use that.

Any other approach is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

the "Blue Prism training" application is a playground for using advanced techniques, and that exact window is done to learn basics of Surface Automation. It's specifically done that way, that it's really hard to work without it, so I really don't think you can go far without using surface..

The exercise that you want to do is pretty hard, so I'd advise on doing simpler one first - reading the first name in the table.

The by-the-book solution to that is as follows:
1) Identify window using region mode
2) Specify a region in the window that contains the "name" field
3) Use the BluePrism OCR to read what's written there and check if that's the one that you're searching for.

If you'll have that exercise done, then you can think about reading the next names.

The simplest way to do that (and it's still not simple!) is to have dynamic region, that will ask for "Start Y", "End Y", "Start X", "End X" parameters. That way, you can specify the parameters for that object and move it as you with. Then using a loop and basic math you can move that region to the next field in table.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, i have already implemented what you suggested, i wanted a different approach where i don't require OCR as there is one other application that i want to automate which contains similar table with data, and there text recognition is failing. I wanted to implement it without OCR, is there a way to do that.

Comment: Well, this applicaiton here is the worst case scenario. There is no win32 mode or AA mode or anything nice to hang on into. All that is left is OCR. ¯\\\_(ツ)_/¯

Well, I hope your other table is much nicer to work with, because otherwise, then it looks like a lot of work.

Comment: I am just using this application for practice. The other application supports both Win32 and Accessibility mode. Is there a way to do the same without ocr.